# Visual Studio function not completing actions in order

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a function that doesn't seem to be working in the intended order.  By the way, this is all in C# in Visual Studio.

Here we have a button that's being clicked (Step4), and what should happen is the button should turn red with the text "Please Wait..." until the process loads, then it'll turn green with the program's name.  However, it's just loading the program and stays default grey with the default text until the process loads, then changes straight to green with the program name.  For some reason it's skipping the red with please wait text part.  Here is the code:

```
    private void Step4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Step4.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
        Step4.Text = "Please Wait...";
        string strMobileStation = "C:\\MWM\\MobileStation\\Station.exe";
        Process MobileStation = Process.Start(strMobileStation);
        MobileStation.WaitForInputIdle();
        Step4.BackColor = Color.Lime;
        Step4.Text = "Mobile Station";
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing this on the user interface thread.

When you do this on the UI thread, you block the UI thread, which in turn means the user interface can't process the messages.  When the method completes, the messages are processed, and the final result is displayed.

The proper way to handle this is to move the "work" (waiting on the process) into a background thread.

You can do this via the `Task` class, ie:

```
private void Step4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Step4.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
    Step4.Text = "Please Wait...";

    Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
    {
      string strMobileStation = "C:\\MWM\\MobileStation\\Station.exe";
      Process MobileStation = Process.Start(strMobileStation);
      MobileStation.WaitForInputIdle();
    })
    .ContinueWith(t =>
    {
      Step4.BackColor = Color.Lime;
      Step4.Text = "Mobile Station";
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Comment: Also, WaitForInputIdle says: "This overload applies only to processes with a user interface and, therefore, a message loop." Consider Process.WaitForExit() instead.

Comment: @ReedCopsey would explicit `Step4.Update();` or `Step4.Refresh();` work in this case, or do they suffere from the same problem?

Comment: @RBarryYoung You'd still lock your UI - and wouldn't work with WPF,etc.  In general, a background thread is the right approach here.

Comment: Ah. Well, there's a 10 year old mystery solved. Really cool solution too! I'd give you a bounty if I could, but you answered it too fast. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For comparison purposes, here's how you would do the same thing using `async` in .Net 4.5:

```
private async void Step4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Step4.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
    Step4.Text = "Please Wait...";

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        string strMobileStation = "C:\\MWM\\MobileStation\\Station.exe";
        Process MobileStation = Process.Start(strMobileStation);
        MobileStation.WaitForInputIdle();
    });

    Step4.BackColor = Color.Lime;
    Step4.Text = "Mobile Station";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try starting and waiting for the processes to start in another thread. `MobileStation.WaitForInputIdle()` is probably blocking the UI thread.

You could use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), which is faily easy to use.